# Best practice between using LEFT JOIN or NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, join, exists

Is there a best practice between using a LEFT JOIN or a NOT EXISTS format?

What is benefit to using one over the other?

If none, which should be preferred?

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B
     ON A.idx = B.idx
WHERE B.idx IS NULL
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT idx FROM tableB B WHERE B.idx = A.idx)
```

I am using queries within Access against a SQL Server database.

Comment: As an aside, the seemingly-identical approach `WHERE A.idx NOT IN (...)` [is **not** identical](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) due to the trivalent behavior of `NULL` (i.e. `NULL` is not equal to `NULL` (nor unequal), therefore if you have *any* `NULL` in `tableB` you will get unexpected results!)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The biggest difference is not in the join vs not exists, it is (as written), the `SELECT *`.

On the first example, you get all columns from *both* `A` and `B`, whereas in the second example, you get only columns from `A`.

In SQL Server, the second variant is slightly faster in a very simple contrived example:

Create two sample tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.A
(
    A_ID INT NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.B
(
    B_ID INT NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
);
GO
```

Insert 10,000 rows into each table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.A DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 10000

INSERT INTO dbo.B DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 10000
```

Remove every 5th row from the second table:

```
DELETE 
FROM dbo.B 
WHERE B_ID % 5 = 1;

SELECT COUNT(*) -- shows 10,000
FROM dbo.A;

SELECT COUNT(*) -- shows  8,000
FROM dbo.B;
```

Perform the two test `SELECT` statement variants:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.A
    LEFT JOIN dbo.B ON A.A_ID = B.B_ID
WHERE B.B_ID IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.B
    WHERE b.B_ID = a.A_ID);
```

Execution plans:

[image]

The second variant does not need to perform the filter operation since it can use the left anti-semi join operator.

Answer (score 40):

Logically they are identical, but `NOT EXISTS` is closer to the AntiSemiJoin that you're asking for, and is generally preferred. It also highlights better that you can't access the columns in B, because it's only used as a filter
(as opposed to having them available with NULL values).

Many years ago (SQL Server 6.0 ish), `LEFT JOIN` was quicker, but that hasn't been the case for a very long time. These days, `NOT EXISTS` is marginally faster.

---

The biggest impact in Access is that the `JOIN` method has to complete the join before filtering it, constructing the joined set in memory. Using `NOT EXISTS` it checks for the row but doesn't allocate space for the columns. Plus, it stops looking once it finds a row. Performance varies a bit more in Access, but a general rule of thumb is that `NOT EXISTS` tends to be a little faster. I'd be less inclined to say it's "best practice", as there are more factors involved.

Comment: "The biggest impact in Access is that the `JOIN` method has to complete the join before filtering it" This also applies to SQL server (2012), and when table B has a lot of rows, the multiplicative nature of the `LEFT JOIN` can, quite literally, blow things way out of proportion: During a test case, I found that my table A with around 3000 rows and table B with around 250K rows produced a combined set of over 750 million(!) rows. With `NOT EXISTS`, the filtering could be applied beforehand, and the total result set never exceeded the number of rows in either table.

Answer (score 10):

An exception I've noticed to the `NOT EXISTS` being superior (however marginally) to `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE IS NULL` is when using **Linked Servers**.

From examining the execution plans, it appears that `NOT EXISTS` operator gets executed in a nested loop fashion. Whereby it is executed on a per row basis (which I suppose makes sense).

Example execution plan demonstrating this behaviour:
[image]

Comment: Linked servers are brutal for that kind of thing.  A possible approach to solving that problem is to copy the remote data over the linked server link using a simple `INSERT INTO #t (a,b,c) SELECT a,b,c FROM LinkedServer.database.dbo.table WHERE x=y` then running the `NOT EXISTS (...)` clause against that temporary copy of the database.

Answer (score 8):

In general, the engine will create an execution plan based essentially on:

1. The number of rows in A and B
2. Whether there is an Index on A and/or B.
3. The expected number of result rows (and intermediate rows)
4. The form of the input query (i.e. your question)

For (4):

The "not exists" plan encourages a seek based plan on table B.  This is a good choice when table A is small and table B is large (and an index exists on B).

The "antijoin" plan is a good choice when table A is very large or table B is very small or no index on B and returning a large result set.

However it is just an "encouragement", like a weighted input. A strong (1),(2),(3) often makes the choice for (4) moot.

( Ignoring the effect of your example returning different columns due to the *. ).

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle

`NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` clauses are not the same functionally or performance wise and,therefore, should be used appropriately.

in some cases they are totally different the `NOT EXISTS` will return only record from table `A` when there is no record in `B` matches, **but** in all type of 'Joins' (left/right full join) it Wil return all records from `A`  and the intersection between two table `A` and `B` which 'NOT EXISTS' will not do
or the only the intersection between two tables or all records from `A` and `B` plus the intersection