# How to select only members who have not made any deposits this month in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am fetching data from two tables, members and fees .I would like to select only those members who have not made any deposit this month. This is what I have tried but the results are not what I am intending to get . any help will be appreciated . I am using mysql .

```
SELECT
    members.memberid, 
    members.companyid, 
    members.name, 
    members.initials, 
    members.surname, 
    members.datejoined,
    members.usercode, 
    members.address, 
    members.cell, 
    members.pic, 
    members.idnumber, members.rank, 
    members.address2,
    fees.feestype,fees.amountpaid,
    fees.companyid,fees.paiddate,
    fees.usercode
FROM 
    members
    INNER JOIN fees
        ON members.memberid = fees.memberid
WHERE 
        MONTH(fees.paiddate) < MONTH(CURDATE())
    AND YEAR(fees.paiddate)  < YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it in a diffent way: choose all members that are not [`IN`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) the set of *members who paid something this month*:

```
SELECT
    memberid, name  /* , and anything you need */
FROM
    members
    /* JOIN fees ON fees.memberid = members.memberid */
WHERE
    memberid NOT IN
    (
    /* members who paid something this month */ 
    SELECT 
        memberid
    FROM
        fees
    WHERE
        YEAR(paiddate)  = YEAR(curdate())  AND
        MONTH(paiddate) = MONTH(curdate())
    ) ;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7113073c92e33fce97b616bd802627ba)*

You actual query specified members who paid something in the years previous to the current one, and month previous to the current one.

---

As a second alternative, you can use [`NOT EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT
    memberid, name  /* , and anything you need */
FROM
    members
    /* JOIN fees ON fees.memberid = members.memberid */
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
    /* any payment from this specific member this month */ 
    SELECT 
        1
    FROM
        fees
    WHERE
        fees.memberid = members.memberid   AND
        YEAR(paiddate)  = YEAR(curdate())  AND
        MONTH(paiddate) = MONTH(curdate())
    ) ;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6ac6e3d0e97aca5577ca0eaaebd8d2aa)*

---

And yet another (not so clear, in my opinion) alternative, do a `LEFT JOIN` and set a `WHERE` condition that will filter out the rows actually retrieving something from the right side of the JOIN (i.e.: using *only* the rows `WHERE` all columns, and specifically `memberid` are NULL on the right side):

```
SELECT
    members.memberid, members.name  /* , and anything you need */
FROM
    members
    /* JOIN fees ON fees.memberid = members.memberid */
    LEFT JOIN /* Imperative to be LEFT JOIN */
    (
    /* members who paid this month */ 
    SELECT 
        fees.memberid
    FROM
        fees
    WHERE
        YEAR(paiddate)  = YEAR(curdate())  AND
        MONTH(paiddate) = MONTH(curdate())
    ) AS s0 
    ON s0.memberid = members.memberid
WHERE
    s0.memberid IS NULL /* The LEFT JOIN produced nothing on the right side */
```

Check [Best practice between using LEFT JOIN or NOT EXISTS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists)

And check all *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f8839c4d5d49f843af8760202f7d9a1d)*

This is called, in relational algebra, an [*antijoin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29)

**UPDATE**

Taking a step further from **Kondybas**'s solution, and as pointed out in the comments to Kondibas answer by **ypercube**, this can be further simplified to:

```
SELECT
    members.memberid, members.name  /* , and anything you need */
FROM
    members
    /* JOIN fees f1 ON fees.memberid = members.memberid */
    LEFT JOIN fees f2 ON 
        f2.memberid = members.memberid AND
        f2.paiddate BETWEEN date_format(curdate() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND curdate()
WHERE
    f2.memberid IS NULL ;
```

Writing the condition like this (i.e.: not having a function applied to paiddate), it will use an index such as:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_member_date ON fees (memberid, paiddate);
```

... as can be seen on the execution plan:

```
id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref                                          | rows | Extra                   
-: | :---------- | :------ | :--- | :-------------- | :-------------- | :------ | :------------------------------------------- | ---: | :-----------------------
 1 | SIMPLE      | members | ALL  | null            | null            | null    | null                                         |    2 |                         
 1 | SIMPLE      | fees    | ref  | idx_member_date | idx_member_date | 5       | fiddle_ZCXLEXEURTHEWEPFKPOV.members.memberid |    1 | Using where; Using index
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6ec80de9aea28c20f55058fa8c5d01ce)*

Comment: I used the first option and it worked so fine . am really impressed about your skills .

Comment: It's called practice.

Comment: Wise versa - we have to reject rows which right part contains everything except NULL - i.e. payments been done this month.

Comment: @Kondybas: no, not really. Double-check the results of all three queries. They're equivalent.

Comment: I mean your description above the code

Comment: @Kondybas: I've changed my wording to make a little more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The third alternative to the **joanolo**'s solutions is to fetch records with NULLs from `LEFT JOIN` of tables:

```
SELECT w.id
  FROM members AS w
  LEFT JOIN fees AS z ON w.memberid = z.memberid
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(z.paiddate, '%Y%M') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%M')
    OR z.paiddate IS NULL
HAVING z.paiddate IS NULL
;
```

As **yupecube** suggested, query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT w.id
  FROM members AS w
  LEFT JOIN fees AS z
         ON w.memberid = z.memberid 
        AND DATE_FORMAT(z.paiddate, '%Y%M') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%M')
 WHERE z.paiddate IS NULL
;
```

The only disadvantage is that JOINs on complex functional conditions are in general very slow.

Comment: SQL99 standard allow to use HAVING clause without GROUP BY under certain circumstances. MySQL at least v.5.6.36 conform it.

Comment: I reword myself, you're nominally right. You can have a `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY`, but I don't think this is what you want. `HAVING` is applied after the aggregation phase of execution of an SQL query... You need some aggregation to be performed, or otherwise it won't work/make sense. You have an implicit aggregation of the *whole table* when you don't have an explicit `GROUP BY`. It's the same case as `SELECT count(*) FROM table HAVING count(*) > 0`. There is aggregation, and you either get one row (with a count > 0) or no rows at all. This is not what I think you intend to do...

Comment: Here is the quite good explanation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: The right way to right this (LEFT JOIN / IS NULL) would be: `SELECT w.id
  FROM members AS w
  LEFT JOIN fees AS z ON w.memberid = z.memberid
 AND DATE_FORMAT(z.paiddate, '%Y%M') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%M')
    WHERE z.paiddate IS NULL ;`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Now I feel dumb.

Comment: No need for that. Feel free to edit your answer ;)

Comment: i upvoted this answer evenif i did not use , it makes more sense to me