# Select All Records From Table That Do Not Exist In Secondary Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

This should be straight forward, but I am getting my tail kicked with the proper syntax.

I have this syntax

```
Select DISTINCT
    bm.Location
    ,bm.[Beer (Upcoming Menu)]
FROM 
    ___SampleRequired bm
LEFT JOIN 
    ___Sample td 
    ON LTRIM(RTRIM(bm.[Beer (Upcoming Menu)])) = LTRIM(RTRIM(td.Beer_name))
WHERE 
    bm.Type LIKE '%Mandate%'
    AND bm.Location = 'StapleChase'
```

which I want to show all beer that exist in the SampleRequired Table that **DO NOT** exist in the Sample Table.  When I execute the above query I get 24 results returned.  My expected returned result set is 23 because

```
BLUE MOON BELGIAN WHITE
```

exists in both of the tables.

How should I change this query so that I **ONLY** get the results that exist in SampleRequired that **DO NOT** exist in Sample?

***Had to use pastebin bc SO complained my post was mostly code...sorry

https://pastebin.com/jH6eX2du

Comment: You could add to WHERE clause `AND td.Beer_name IS NULL`

Comment: That does it...care to explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
Select DISTINCT
    bm.Location
    ,bm.[Beer (Upcoming Menu)]
FROM 
    ___SampleRequired bm
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 
    FROM ___Sample td 
    WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(bm.[Beer (Upcoming Menu)])) = LTRIM(RTRIM(td.Beer_name)))
AND bm.Type LIKE '%Mandate%'
AND bm.Location = 'StapleChase'
```

Also, [Max Vernon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10832/max-vernon) has a nice [answer comparing LEFT JOIN vs NOT EXIST](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists) It's also more common to see this in the wild versus the `LEFT JOIN` method where you also need to add `table.key IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause. i.e `td.Beer_name IS NULL`

And, [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) comparing [NOT IN vs NOT EXIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists).

Comment: This method returns the expected results but does it keep into account my WHERE clause?      bm.Type LIKE '%Mandate%'
    AND bm.Location = 'StapleChase'

Comment: Fixed @JamesL i forgot to add that

Answer (score 1):

Although I think [scsimon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/95107/scsimon) answer is da best, you can get the same result by adding:

```
AND td.Beer_name IS NULL
```

LEFT JOIN selects all rows from `__SampleRequired` table that match WHERE condition, but add nulls for those `__Sample` rows that do not match ON condition.

Comment: The WHERE condition is processed after the join (in Postgresql), but in this case at least it amounts to the same thing.